# Basic JavaScript Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm having a little trouble with this basic JavaScript Mortgage calculator... I haven't implemented the math yet. But I am having trouble displaying the final sum (x + y + z) below the form after it has been submitted(It's client-side, and I'm just using the sum of the variables to test it). Also, the reset form button doesn't work. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- This is assign05.html -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> JavaScriptcript Mortgage Calculator </title>
    <script>

    // Pass values into variables
    function myFunction() {
        var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("apr").value);
        var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("loanTerm").value);
        var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("loanAmount").value);
    }

    //Display the total sum
    function display(x, y, z) {
        var num = x + y + z;
        var n = num.toString();
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = n;
    }

    // Validate the form
    function validateForm(x, y, z) {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["apr"].value;
        var y = document.forms["myForm"]["loanTerm"].value;
        var z = document.forms["myForm"]["loanAmount"].value;

        // If statements
        if (x==null || x=="") {
            alert("APR must be filled out");
            document.getElementById("apr").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if (y==null || y=="") {
            alert("Loan Term must be filled out");
            document.getElementById("loanTerm").focus()
            return false;
        }
        else if (z==null || z=="") {
            alert("Loan Amount must be filled out");
            document.getElementById("loanAmount").focus()
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // Call and display the sum. (This isn't working)
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = display(x, y, z);
        }

        //Reset the form (this isn't working)
        function resetForm() {
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad=document.getElementById("apr").focus();>
    <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        APR: <input type="number" id="apr" value=""><br/>
        Loan Term: <input type="number" id="loanTerm" value=""><br/>
        Loan Amount: <input type="number" id="loanAmount" value=""><br/>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate Payment Button</button>
        <input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset form">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your div (or other element)  with id "demo" that the information will be injected into. If it does not exist then javascript can't write into it.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? The `validateForm` function is not closed properly.

Comment: I fixed the validateForm closing brace, but Daniel, I don't understand what you mean... I didn't think I needed a div element

Comment: @CSStudent In your `validateForm` function, you were referencing an element with id `demo`, which doesn't exist in your html, therefore the output is not displaying (actually in your code, you need to add an element with id `total` to display the result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a certain things wrong with your code. I'll mention them first:

1. `validateForm` function is not closed properly. It should be something like:

   ```
   function validateForm(x, y, z) {
       var x = document.forms["myForm"]["apr"].value;
       var y = document.forms["myForm"]["loanTerm"].value;
       var z = document.forms["myForm"]["loanAmount"].value;

       // If statements
       if (x==null || x=="") {
           alert("APR must be filled out");
           document.getElementById("apr").focus();
           return false;
       }
       else if (y==null || y=="") {
           alert("Loan Term must be filled out");
           document.getElementById("loanTerm").focus()
           return false;
       }
       else if (z==null || z=="") {
           alert("Loan Amount must be filled out");
           document.getElementById("loanAmount").focus()
           return false;
       }
       else {
           // Call and display the sum. (This isn't working)
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = display(x, y, z);
       }
   } //end of function definition
   ```
2. You're passing the values of inputs to display function as strings. You need to parse them as integers in your `validateForm` method.
3. In the `resetForm` method you refer to the form by doing a `document.getElementById("myForm")`. However, the `form` element doesn't have that `id`.
4. You can completely do away with `myFunction()` that you call when the "CalculatePayment" button is clicked and call the `validateForm` method instead over there.
5. There is no `div` with `id` "demo" or "total" which you seem to write to. And you explicitly write to one div in the `display` function and then again you do this:

   ```
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = display(x, y, z); 
    //display function already writes to a div. This is redundant
   ```

Taking all these pointers into account, I've created a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdzjL8v/1/) that seems to be working like you want to with minimal modifications to your code and some tidying up of course. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some points regarding the code you posted:

- Your `validateForm` function is not closed properly, and it leads to syntax error
- there is no element with id `myForm` in your html, and your `resetForm` function is trying to reset this non-existing element

I have modified your code slightly, you may try the following:

#### HTML

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="validateForm(); return false;" method="post">
      APR: <input type="number" id="apr" value=""><br/>
      Loan Term: <input type="number" id="loanTerm" value=""><br/>
            Loan Amount: <input type="number" id="loanAmount" value=""><br/>

      <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate Payment Button</button>
      <input type="button" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset form">
</form>
<div id="total"></div>
```

### JS

```
// Pass values into variables
function myFunction() {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("apr").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("loanTerm").value);
    var z = parseInt(document.getElementById("loanAmount").value);
}

//Display the total sum
function display(x, y, z) {
    var num = x + y + z;
    var n = num.toString();
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = n;
}

// Validate the form
function validateForm(x, y, z) {
    var x = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["apr"].value);
    var y = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["loanTerm"].value);
    var z = parseInt(document.forms["myForm"]["loanAmount"].value);

    // If statements
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("APR must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("apr").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (y==null || y=="") {
        alert("Loan Term must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("loanTerm").focus()
        return false;
    }
    else if (z==null || z=="") {
        alert("Loan Amount must be filled out");
        document.getElementById("loanAmount").focus()
        return false;
    }
    else {

    // Call and display the sum. (This isn't working)
    display(x, y, z);
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = display(x, y, z);
    }
    return false;
}

//Reset the form (this isn't working)
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

Comment: Oh, that seems to work. I think I'm beginning to understand! (Sorry, Im new at javascript) Now how would I have it so that when it displays, it actualy gives me the sum, not a string of x, y, z?

Comment: In your `validateForm` function, `x, y, z` are declared as `String` variables, so `+` will give you string concatenation, not arithmetic addition. A quick fix is to explicitly convert these values to integers using `parseInt` (see my updated solution)

Answer (score 1):

- String(num) works better than 123.toString()
- You're not returning anything from display() but you're using the return value.
- Your x, y, and z are strings, but I'd suggest turning them into numbers before doing the math.
- < form name="myForm" should say < form id="myForm"

Comment: As you can see, I'm new to stack overflow as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the reset button you can just basically make it a button. Just make it like:

```
<button>Reset form</button>
```

When you click it all the form's content will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have not used any id with , use `id="myForm"`, then reset button will work perfectly.
2. Close your validate function properly.
3. You have not add any place for showing your result.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,i realise that you want to display the total of x,y,z in the empty div with an Id of  total at the end of your html code,why not use textContent to display your result instead of innerHTML.Besides,your buttons are not submit type.I mean the buttons inside the form.
Note that when you make the buttons submit type,you have to use the inbuilt javascript function of preventDefault(event); at the top.